# How to get user id in session?

Tags: php, session

Kinda noob problem but I'm working on it for about 2 hours and I can't solve this

I have a login system which works fine (thanks tutorials), but now I'd like to save the ID in the session when user's logging

This is my login.php:

```
<?php session_start();
require_once 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])){
 $uname = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
 $umail = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
 $upass = $_POST['txt_password'];
 $sth = $bdd->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name=$uname");
 $sth->execute();
 $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $uid = $result;

 if($user->login($uname,$umail,$upass)){
            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $uname;
            $_SESSION['user_mail'] = $umail;
            $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $uid;
            $uname = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];


            $umail = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
            $upass = $_POST['txt_password'];
            var_dump($_SESSION['user_name']);
            $user->redirect('index.php');
         } else {
            $error = "Wrong Details !";
         } 
   }
?>
```

The var_dump of $_SESSION['user_name'] works, but when I do var_dump($_SESSION['user_id']);, it shows "null"

I don't know at all what's the problem .. Someone got a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: I am sure you would have the solution if you had done a research.

Comment: What do I have to research ? .-.

Comment: share your HTML form code, you might get working solution

Answer (score 0):

It's NOT an answer but pointing you in right direction and highlighting the errors you have in your code,

```
<?php session_start();
require_once 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])){
 $uname = $_POST['txt_uname_email']; //Here $_POST Same
 $umail = $_POST['txt_uname_email']; //Here $_POST Same
 $upass = $_POST['txt_password'];
 $sth = $bdd->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name=$uname");
 $sth->execute();
 $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $result = $_SESSION['user_id']; // What is this,?
 $uid = $result; // What is this?

 //You are not fetching any data from database against your SELECT query

 if($user->login($uname,$umail,$upass)){
    //Here you are setting POST variables as session, thats why you are getting $_SESSION['user_name'] on var_dump
            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $uname;
            $_SESSION['user_mail'] = $umail;
            $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id']; //Where is this coming from
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $uid; //It can't be eqaul to $result;
            $uname = $_POST['txt_uname_email']; // Mistake
            $umail = $_POST['txt_uname_email']; // Mistake
            $upass = $_POST['txt_password']; // Mistake
            var_dump($_SESSION['user_name']);
            $user->redirect('index.php');
         } else {
            $error = "Wrong Details !";
         } 
   }
?>
```